# Getting "Object() takes no arguments" error while making a object

Tags: python

I have researched a lot about it and checked my codes for typo several times but stil I am not able to resolve this issue:

This is the survey.py class

```
class AnonymousSurvey:
    """Collect anonymous answers to a survey question."""


def __init__(self, question):
    """Store a question, and prepare to store responses."""
    self.question = question
    self.responses = []


def show_question(self):
    """Show the survey question."""
    print(self.question)


def store_response(self, new_response):
    """Store a single response to the survey."""
    self.responses.append(new_response)


def show_results(self):
    """Show all the responses that have been given."""
    print("Survey results:")
    for response in self.responses:
        print(f"- {response}")
```

And this is language_survey.py

```
from survey import AnonymousSurvey

# Define a question, and make a survey.
question = "What language did you first learn to speak?"
my_survey = AnonymousSurvey(question)

# Show the question, and store responses to the question.
my_survey.show_question()
print("Enter 'q' at any time to quit.\n")
while True:
    response = input("Language: ")
    if response == 'q':
        break
    my_survey.store_response(response)

# Show the survey results.
print("\nThank you to everyone who participated in the survey!")
my_survey.show_results()
```

Whenever I am trying to run the language_survey.py I am getting following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...\survey_que\language_survey.py", line 5, in <module>
    my_survey = AnonymousSurvey(question)
TypeError: AnonymousSurvey() takes no arguments
```

Comment: This looks like an indentation problem: You should indent the methods below the class definition. Otherwise, you define an empty class and a bunch of unrelated functions.

Comment: @MartinWettstein Thank you very much this really solved it. I am actually new to programming that's why such minor thing go unnoticed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this copy pasted from the file? If so you need to indent all the `def`s in `survey.py` so that python will recognize them as a part of your class:

```
class AnonymousSurvey:
    """Collect anonymous answers to a survey question."""


    def __init__(self, question):
        """Store a question, and prepare to store responses."""
        self.question = question
        self.responses = []


    def show_question(self):
        """Show the survey question."""
        print(self.question)


    def store_response(self, new_response):
        """Store a single response to the survey."""
        self.responses.append(new_response)


    def show_results(self):
        """Show all the responses that have been given."""
        print("Survey results:")
        for response in self.responses:
            print(f"- {response}")
```

Comment: Yes it's pasted from the file. And it was indeed the issue thank you very much.